# DateTime Parse With Specific Culture Is Not Working

Tags: vb.net, datetime, culture

I have a website with two languages, English and Arabic. Since my windows uses English, when the website is on the "en-US" culture, everything works fine but the moment i change to "ar-JO", i starts getting exceptions.

I then tried to parse each date with a specific culture ("en-US"). My problem is that even this didn't work.

```
DateTime.Parse(txt_LoginTime.Text,New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

When i use the above code without the culture, i get an exception and when i use it with the culture, i get the following output:

```
3/27/2016 12:00:00 ص
```

Now the problem is in the Arabic letter which represents AM/PM. As i understand, since i am using the "en-US" culture, this is suppose to be all English. Can anybody help identity the source of the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: what is the input? `"en-US"` wont parse an Arabic datestring any more than it always do so with a UK date.

Comment: If it doesn't then whats the point of using it ? The input is "3/26/2016"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have AM with an hour of 12 which doesn't make a lot of sense.  You can create a custom culture with code below that will use US numbers and Arabic AM/PM

```
Imports System.Globalization
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = "3/27/2016 00:00:00 ص"
        Dim culture As New MyCulture
        Dim _date As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss t", culture)
    End Sub

End Module

Public Class MyCulture
    Inherits CultureInfo

    Sub New()
        MyBase.New(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name)
        Me.DateTimeFormat.AMDesignator = "ص"
        Me.DateTimeFormat.PMDesignator = "م"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hour 12 is noon which is PM.  Midnight is 00:00 which is AM, not 12:00.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using AM/PM with 24 hour format.